# Xcode iPhone SDK "Terminating app due to uncaught exception"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, crash

I have a problem with my application for the iPhone.

It's a tab based application. In one of the tabs, I have a Table View. I have set it up to load in data from a PLIST.

My problem is that when I try to build and run it, the application either crashes, or stays at a black screen with the error message "Terminating app due to uncaught exception".

I looked in the console, and found that the error probably laid in this string:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return workouts.count;
}
```

(error message:)

```
2010-02-06 21:50:54.733 Mudo[52439:207] *** -[FirstViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x39101a0
2010-02-06 21:50:54.735 Mudo[52439:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[FirstViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x39101a0'
2010-02-06 21:50:54.736 Mudo[52439:207] Stack: (
    29344859,
    2569487625,
    29726779,
    29296246,
    29148866,
    4413562,
    4420938,
    4419935,
    3136474,
    3076985,
    3118420,
    3106975,
    55857840,
    55857263,
    55855302,
    55854394,
    2780921,
    2804616,
    2787027,
    2814133,
    37441233,
    29129600,
    29125704,
    2780777,
    2818051
)
```

Building the app does not generate any errors.

Please help me? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you show us your @interface declaration for the class? It sounds like you haven't declared your FirstViewController as a UITableViewController Subclass or you haven't set the table view's delegate/datasource correctly...

Comment: @interface FirstView : UIViewController 
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
 NSArray *workouts;
}


@end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the actual text of the exception, `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[FirstViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x39101a0'`, you can see the root of the problem. Somewhere in your code you're calling `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` on a `FirstViewController`, which doesn't implement that method.

Exceptions are not caught at compile-time, but rather thrown at runtime. You may want to read up on them if you aren't familiar, as they're a fairly important part of many programming languages.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling

Comment: How do I implement that, in that case, then?

Comment: Wait a minute,
I don't have any code in my FirstViewController-file.. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Of course it has something to do with that. If you've set FirstViewController to be the table's datasource/delegate then it needs to implement the methods from those protocols!

Comment: Yep. The solution is either to implement the method, or to not call it in the first place. If it's being called by mistake, (ie you have another view controller that is a `UITableViewController`) then don't call it. If that's supposed to be the controller, though, you'll have to implement the necessary methods. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I'm pretty confused about this..
The file my current code is in is FirstView.h/m.
The file that my interface for that tab is FirstView.xib.
The file the TableView wants to get loaded from is FirstViewController.h/m.

In interface builder, I hooked up the dataSource and delegate to "File's Owner".

I don't understand why it wants to be shown from the FirstViewController.h/m file..? Could deleting that file fix it? I don't really need it...

Comment: Crap. Deleting them does definetely not fix the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, since FirstViewController is one of the standard example classes created when starting a new Tab Bar based application in Xcode that you haven't changed its super class or implemented the methods of `UITabeViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

Either that or you've implemented the methods from those protocols in another class, but set FirstViewController as the table view's delegate/datasource.

We need more information to know for sure.

Comment: Hm, you're right.. I obviously set the TableView's delegate and datasource to FirstViewController.. How do I change this..?
Thanks :)